# what is the diffrence between facebook canvas url and secure canvas url

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

diffrence between facebook canvas url and secure canvas url?
In Iframe always secure canvas url content opens,then what is the need of canvas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secure canvas URL is used by users browsing Facebook over HTTPS

The canvas URL is used by users browsing Facebook over HTTP

This is documented here: https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas

Comment: Thank you lgy for your reply.
 i am using third party secure canvas url. 
My issue is i want my friends to be redirect to some specific url instead of canvas App once they accept my App request.
how to approach this ?

Comment: How you do that isn't related to this being a Facebook app - once you process the incoming request, redirect the browser the same way you would on any other page